# Problem when converting Shapefile to KML files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, kml

I select Layer CRS as WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
When I open the kml layer in Google earth it is wrong. In Google earth, appears some segments every where on the globe. Can anyone explain to me what is the wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting the CRS?  Are you doing this on the layer itself or as part of the export process?

Answer (score 1):

Check for your settings:
[image]

now rightclick on layer and save as kml:
[image]