# QGIS export to KML goes wrong

Tags: qgis, google-earth

I have a next problem, when I convert my .shp file to .kml the polylines are all over the globe in Google Earth.

.SHP file is made in Autocad MAP 3D - export to shp. Note that MAP 3D is not creating .prj file so it cannot be opened in Google Earth pro.

I have made settings according to that question in the link below:

[Problem when converting Shapefile to KML files in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/102649/problem-when-converting-shapefile-to-kml-files-in-qgis)

Here are photos of input:

[image]

And here are photos of Google Earth output:

[image]

Any idea how to get proper output?

...I have opened .shp in QGis and saved it as ESRI .shp but Google Earth says it that it cannot be projected because coordinates are "out of area". I have set a WGS84 coordinate system in QGis.

Comment: Have you tried to import directly the shapefile in Google Earth Pro? Google Earth Pro is free, and you can import directly shapefile into it without conveting the data to KML.

Comment: Hello, I tried but problem is that my .shp is created from Autocad Map 3D which does not create .prj file it creates .dbf, .idx. shp. .shx. and cannot be  projected into Google Earth.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: The coordinates in your sceenshot do not look like latlong degrees, as needed for EPSG:4326. Are you sure your data aligns with a well-known-background, like Openstreetmap from the QuickMapServices plugin in QGIS? If the file was made with Autocad, I assume you have some CRS that uses meters as units, but not EPSG:4326.

Comment: Hello, that is correct in my autocad my units are meters, I made SHX file from D48-Gauss Krueger (EPSG:3857), probably I have to change D48 to EPSG:4326 and than export to new .shp (and than open in Google Earth pro. But than I have a problem that Google Earth opens my .shp but it place it somwhere in Guinea bay.

Comment: D48-Gauss Krueger is **NOT** EPSG:3857, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43402/reprojection-from-wgs-to-slovenian-gauss-kruger-in-qgis and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159178/autocad-dxf-to-qgis-and-exporting-to-kml-for-viewing-in-google-maps for the right EPSG codes. **DO** **NOT** use `Set CRS of the Layer`, but rather save the file to another filename and different CRS. And always check against Openstreetmap background if the layer is in the right part of the globe.

Comment: Yes true. I needed to set my CRS (of the .shp) to EPSG3912 and than save as .kml in WGS84 CRS. Now it works fine.Thanks for help!